# Powershell to match the pattern at end of string and print the first part of the string

Tags: string, powershell

I have a string "dep-value-sync-excess-v12" or "dep-value-sync-excess-v100" ,

The pattern to be matched is anything that ends with -v and print "dep-value-sync-excess"

I am able to pattern match but not print the first part of string

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please remember to add your coding attempt to the question

Comment: ("dep-value-sync-excess-v12" -split "-v\d{1,}")[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*The pattern to be matched is anything that ends with ... print the first part of string*"
Means: **Remove (replace with nothing) the last part of the string**

Thus, using the [`-Replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator):

```
$String = "dep-value-sync-excess-v12", "dep-value-sync-excess-v100"
$String -Replace '-v\d+$'
dep-value-sync-excess
dep-value-sync-excess
```

Regular Expression explanation:

- `-v` literal match
- `\d+` matches one or more numeric digits
- `$` matches the end of the string